# Qt Application visually freezes after start or return from background

Tags: android, qt5, android-9.0-pie

We have a (rather complicated) Qt application, with port to Android. It worked quite OK - until we started trying it on Android Pie.
Sometimes, either after start, or after return from background, application visually freezes - however, logging shows that UI thread is alive, it responds to taps, widgets receive paintEvent()'s and process them. But nothing changes on screen.

Hardware buttons like 'Back' also work - application is able to show 'Are you sure to exit?" message box and it works properly.

Also, you you try to go ot home screen and back to app - most of the time it unfreezes.

Actually, this behavior started on Android 8, but was resolve with a dirty hack - doing hide/show for main widget upon receiving applicationStateChange(Active). But it stopped working on Android 9.

I am completely out of ideas what could we do to produce such behavior, and how to fix that...

Comment: Forgot to mention - I'm using Qt 5.11.3. Unfortunately, cannot use 5.12 - since it would require going from gcc to clang, and that's not what we have resources for now.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experience a similar problem with a native android project and can't find any explanation why this might be happening

Answer (score 0):

After a long and rather tedious debugging we finally narrowed it to a problem in Qt itself.
I've reported a bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-76142

However, I don't know whether it was fixed in newer releases, since we stopped development of Android apps for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an actual solution, but shares some ideas. I used QT 6.3 and the same hang/freeze problem occurred in qt android app (arm64-v8a / Qt widgets) after returning from background or after phone auto off when app is opened and after return to phone on. Another consequence is that after sending the app to background, I can't use Google chrome properly (I only tested this app, not other apps). What happened is that it's very slow and scrolling in Chrome doesn't work as usual.

I suppressed this problem with this trick (not a solution): i.e., before sending the QT app to the background, I triggered it to show a message box (from clicking a button) and let message box open. Now the Google Chrome app worked normally. And after dragging the QT app to the front and giving OK to the message box, I was able to use the application as usual. No hang/freeze problem.

Also I read an article from a link (https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2014-November/014218.html) : That is, we can able to modify the QtActivity.java (which can communicate to the QT app) and use the on pause and on resume event. So what I thought is that, If I trigger the app to show Qt message box from this "on pause" event, and automatically close the same in the "on resume" event this hang/freeze can be handled.

But I didn't try above (modify QtActivity.java) because now I switched to QT 6.4 and hang/freeze problem is not present in this version.